# Terminal Width issues with Linux Screen

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, gnu-screen, arch-linux

I'm having issues where when I'm in a regular SSH terminal, with $TERM set to `xterm-256color`, and the terminal width is very small (narrow) in Linux Screen.  I'm running Arch Linux.  When I'm in the default SSH terminal (detached from a screen session), then my terminal width is fine, it goes all the way across.  However, when I initiate screen, my terminal width narrows by a lot, and all my files are either wrapped or truncated.  It goes from about 1400 columns to 80 columns; it's pretty bad.  Any ideas to how to have it work in screen the way it works in the regular terminal?  I'm not able to use screen the way I need to until I get this resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is. I thought I'd let you know about **dtach**:

> dtach is a program that emulates the
>   detach feature of screen. It is
>   designed to be transparent and
>   un-intrusive; it avoids interpreting
>   the input and output between attached
>   terminals and the program under its
>   control. Consequently, it works best
>   with full-screen applications such as
>   emacs.
>
> dtach is intended for users who want
>   the detach feature of screen without
>   the other overhead of screen. It is
>   tiny, does not use many libraries, and
>   stays out of the way as much as
>   possible.

I use it all the time. Screen is overkill for me. Sounds like it might work for you as well.

**EDIT: usage example**

Here is what I do for switching. It might be too much hassle for you. Though maybe you could make some aliases in your bash rc file. dtach works with socket files. So first I:

```
# dtach -A firsttask bash
```

Then start whatever task in the bash shell. Then leave it that dtach "session"

```
Ctrl-\
```

Start another dtach session:

```
# dtach -A secondtask bash
```

Using -A rather than -a will create the socket if it does not exist. If it does exist, it will not execute the specified command, just connect.

So if you want a set up with certain tasks that you always do, like you describe, it is possible. Bash aliases will make this convenient. You'll have one key stroke (Ctrl-\) to disconnect, and then an alias to connect. So a few more key strokes than screen.

You could make an alias for

```
alias log='dtach -A tailtask tail -f /var/log/messages'
```

in your .bashrc file and then just punch in 'log' and hit enter. If you dtach, it keeps running.

I just like dtach because it is small and I thought it was so cool how I can connect to the same socket twice. This means I can do "online" nix training for my friends who want to use the "new cool ubuntu thing". :P You can probably do something similar with screen I guess.

Comment: Man, this is sweet, but it unfortunately isn't going to work for me as a solution.  I'm needing the functionality of screen in regards to switches between two or more windows.  Reason being is I'm going to have a tail -f running in one screen and vim pulled up with source code in another, and possibly an FTP or some sort of remote connection in the third window for uploading/pulling remote files.

Comment: Well, here is how I achieve that. It may be to much hassle for you though. Dtach works with socket files. So I do something like... Well, I'll add this to my answer since it has nice formating.

Comment: +1 for an interesting and useful solution. However, what's the *overhead of screen* that we're avoiding? I never knew that screen was that heavy.

Comment: Well, obviously he was having other issues - nothing to do with overhead. I was quoting the man page. dtach is 18760 bytes and screen is 376112 bytes on the machine I'm typing on right now. For me, not an issue really. Just a preference. For embedded or virtual machines, it can be nice to only have a very lean set of tools. So small, dtach is on my list of tools to install.

Comment: not an answer. downvoted and adding bounty, same thing happens to me :/

Answer (score 2):

As per https://superuser.com/questions/217066/prevent-gnu-screen-from-resizing-display-size

Try adding this (from /etc/screenrc) to your ~/.screenrc:

```
# Change the xterm initialization string from is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>
# (This fixes the "Aborted because of window size change" konsole symptoms found
#  in bug #134198)
termcapinfo xterm* 'is=\E[r\E[m\E[2J\E[H\E[?7h\E[?1;4;6l'
```

You may need to change the "xterm" to match your $TERM.

Comment: This 13-year-old question was still amazingly relevant, and this is the working solution. Thank you Joshua :)